# How to resolve "Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied." error?

Tags: c#, .net-core, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

I am using neo4jclient graph database with .net core API. I have to add the health checks. I have created my own health check using Ihealthcheck interface. below is my healthcheck class

public class DatabaseHealthCheck : IHealthCheck

```
{
    public DatabaseHealthCheck(IGraphClient graphClient)
    {
        _graphClient = graphClient;
    }

    private readonly IGraphClient _graphClient;
    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
        HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))

    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _graphClient.Cypher.Match(@"show databases")
            .Return((n) => n.As<DatabaseDetail>()).ResultsAsync;

            foreach (var res in result)
            {
                if (res.currentStatus == "Online")
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(
                           HealthCheckResult.Healthy("Healthy"));
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HealthCheckResult(status: context.Registration.FailureStatus, exception: ex);
        }

        return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();

        //    return await Task.FromResult(
        //        new HealthCheckResult(context.Registration.FailureStatus,
        //        "Unhealthy"));
    }
}
```

With this health check I want to get the database details and then check the status of database weather it is online or not but I am getting the below error

Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're writing will not return anything, what you're actually executing is:

```
MATCH (show databases)
RETURN n
```

You can see this if you change your code to look like this:

```
var query = _graphClient.Cypher.Match(@"show databases")
           .Return((n) => n.As<string>());
           
var text = query.Query.DebugQueryText;
var result = await query.ResultsAsync;
```

If you put a breakpoint in so you can see what the `text` variable will be you'll be able to see it.

Now! I can't think how to get what you want when you're using the `GraphClient` - it might be possible with the `BoltGraphClient` - but the error you're getting implies you're using the former.

IF you were on the `BoltGraphClient`, you *could* access the `Driver` and execute:

```
var session = ((BoltGraphClient)_graphClient).Driver.AsyncSession(d => d.WithDatabase("system"));
var cursor = await session.RunAsync("SHOW DATABASES");
while (await cursor.FetchAsync())
{
    var name = cursor.Current.Values["name"].As<string>();
    var status = cursor.Current.Values["currentStatus"].As<string>();
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} is {status.ToUpperInvariant()}");
}
```

I don't know any other work around with the http `GraphClient` - it would need to be added to the client. In theory - it's not a complex PR to do if you wanted to.

Comment: Hello Charlotte

When I using your boltgraphclient code. I got the below error

{"code":403,"message":"Unable to resolve service for type 'Neo4jClient.BoltGraphClient' while attempting to activate 'RecommenderModel.DatabaseHealthCheck'."}

Thanks

Comment: You would need to change the URI as well... so you would have `new BoltGraphClient("neo4j://URI:7687", "user", "pass");`

Comment: I am getting this error Now
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'

Comment: I have no idea what that means, you're going to need to put all the code, including construction of the client in your question so I can see if there is anything in afraid

Comment: i am getting this error Now..
Failed to connect to any routing server. Please make sure that the cluster is up and can be accessed by the driver and retry.

Comment: You need to augment your question with how you create your graph client and what version of Neo4j you are using...

Comment: Hello Charlotte. Thank you for your help. I have resolved the error and now I am getting the proper response

Comment: Hello charlotte. can you help me in this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157186/how-to-write-user-defined-functions-and-stored-procedure-query-of-cipher-of-neo4