# How to write user defined functions and stored procedure query of cipher of neo4j in .net core?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, asp.net-core-3.1, neo4jclient

I have a query like that

```
call apoc.load.json("url") yield value
     unwind value.learningPaths as val
                 merge (n:learningPaths {id:val.uid}) Set n.modified = val.last_modofied,
                 n.type     = val.type,
                 n.locale   = val.locale,
                 n.childrens= val.number_of_children,
                 n.summary  = val.summary,
                 n.minutes  = val.duration_in_minutes,
                 n.title    = val.title,
                 n.levels = val.levels,
                 n.roles = val.roles,
                 n.modules = val.modules,
                 n.products = val.products
```

How can I write that query in .net core API to add data in neo4j database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fluent api contains everything you need here, so:

```
await client.Cypher.Call("apoc.load.json('url')").Yield("value")
        .Unwind("value.learningPaths", "val")
        .Merge("(n:learningPaths {id:val.uid})")
        .Set(@"n.modified = val.last_modofied,
                     n.type     = val.type,
                     n.locale   = val.locale,
                     n.childrens= val.number_of_children,
                     n.summary  = val.summary,
                     n.minutes  = val.duration_in_minutes,
                     n.title    = val.title,
                     n.levels = val.levels,
                     n.roles = val.roles,
                     n.modules = val.modules,
                     n.products = val.products")
                     .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

What I might look at if I were you is whether you can just shorten the `SET` to just use `=` to set all the properties:

```
await client.Cypher.Call("apoc.load.json('url')").Yield("value")
        .Merge("(n:learningPaths {id:val.uid})")
        .Set(@"n = val")
        .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

Or maybe a `+=` if you need it to be additive:

```
await client.Cypher.Call("apoc.load.json('url')").Yield("value")
        .Merge("(n:learningPaths {id:val.uid})")
        .Set(@"n += val")
        .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

It's going to depend on what exactly `val` has though, have a read through of the [SET](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/) documentation (maybe [Replacing Properties](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-replace-properties-using-map) or [Mutating properties](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-setting-properties-using-map)).

Comment: Hello @charlotte. I am using your code
  var result = await _graphClient.Cypher.Call("apoc.load.json('url')')").Yield("value")
        .Merge("(n:learningPaths {id:val.uid})")
        .Set(@"n = val")
        .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
                return result;

I am getting the below error
cannot assign void to a implicitly typed variable

Comment: You've added `var results = ` to the beginning - but there are no results. So you just need to remove that to get it working!

Comment: but I have to assign in a variable and than return the variable

Comment: You're not doing that in your query. That doesn't return anything - if you want to return something - you'll need to add a `.Return` statement at the end

Comment: ok I have added the return and resolved the error thank you

Comment: Hello @charlotte, I got error with your query
Variable `val` not defined and also I have use unwind in my query but you have not used unwind in your query

Comment: Sorry - I missed that - I've updated the answer to include the unwind!

Comment: hello @charlotte
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631544/how-to-write-cipher-query-in-net-core-api