# How to write Cypher query in .net core API

Tags: asp.net-core, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a Cypher query like that

```
MATCH (n: learningPaths) 
WHERE any(x IN n.modules WHERE x = "any course")
RETURN n
```

How can I write this query in .net core API to get the results

Previously I have a query like that

```
MATCH (n:learningPaths)-[]->(m:modules) 
WHERE m.id = "any course" 
RETURN n;
```

and I write below in .net core API

```cs
var result = (
    await _graphClient.Cypher
          .Match(@"(n:learningPaths)-[]->(m:modules)")
          .Where<modules>(m => m.id == "any course")
          .Return((n)=>  n.As<learningPaths>())
          .ResultsAsync)
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried looking here? https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just doing:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Match("MATCH (n:learningPaths)-->(m:modules)")
    .Where("any(x IN n.modules WHERE x = 'any course')"
    .Return( n => n.As<learningPaths>());
```

Comment: Hello @charlotte. yes your query is working but how can I pass dynamic values in place of any course in
.Where("any(x IN n.modules WHERE x = 'any course')"

Comment: It's just a string, so you could use interpolation, or format.

Comment: Cypher.Match(@"(n:learningPaths)") .Where("any(x IN n.modules WHERE x = '{{coursename}}')").Return( n => n.As<learningPaths>());
I have used like that but it is not working

Comment: You've not put the $ symbol in front of the "

Comment: Hello @charlotte
I am getting the below error when I use $ in query Cypher.Match(@"(n:learningPaths)") .Where("any(x IN n.modules WHERE x = $'{{coursename}}')").Return( n => n.As<learningPaths>()); "Invalid input '$': expected \"+\" or \"-\"

Comment: You aren't using string interpolation - `...Cypher.Match(...).Where($"(any...)")`

Comment: I have also tried that but it is also not return anything like that
Cypher.Match(@"(n:learningPaths)") .Where($"any(x IN n.modules WHERE x = '{{coursename}}')").Return( n => n.As<learningPaths>());

Comment: Anything like what? - also you have double `{{` which is an escape character. - your where should look like this: `.Where($"any(x IN n.modules WHERE x = '{coursename}')")`

Comment: Hello @charlotte. can you check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832244/failed-after-retried-for-6-times-in-30000-ms-when-accessing-api-with-neo4j-database