# Failed after retried for 6 times in 30000 ms when accessing API with neo4j database

Tags: asp.net-core, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

Initially when I accessing the API with neo4j database it works properly but after some time when I try to access the API I got the error below:

```
Failed after retried for 6 times in 30000 ms. Make sure that your database is online and retry again.
```

I am using the code below for database connection in API:

```
var neo4jClient = new BoltGraphClient(new Uri(connectionUrl), Username, Password);
neo4jClient.ConnectAsync();
services.AddSingleton<IBoltGraphClient>(neo4jClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no real coding answer here, the only thing that sticks out to me is a lack of `await` before the `neo4jClient.ConnectAsync()` call.

Other than that, you'd need to check the connection, network etc. If it's local - then I'm not sure - I guess you can try/catch this - but that's kind of what has happened under the hood.

Comment: If I use await before neo4jClient.ConnectAsync() than I need to make ConfigureServices() method async. When I do that then getting exception in authorization service

Comment: OK, well, then use `Wait` - as in `neo4jClient.ConnectAsync().Wait()`

Comment: I have use Wait - as in neo4jClient.ConnectAsync().Wait() but still getting error mentioned in question

Comment: you have any other solution

Comment: Nope, it's not a code thing - it's your setup - is it a local db? Firewalls? amount of hits there's so many things that it could be